# selectonemenu with the error java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

Tags: java, jsf

I want to fill a selectonemenu but always I have this error :

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
```

this is the code:

```
public class ToolsJIRA implements Serializable{

private String myChoicePeriod;

 //getters and setters
}
```

**JSF:**

```
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ToolsJIRA.myChoicePeriod}">
                   <f:selectItem itemValue="Month" value="Month"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemValue="Week" value="Week"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemValue="Year" value="Year"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I have found  that I should write a converter but I don't Know why? beacause I have seen some example work without a converter??

thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this code in in your webpage

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{checkBoxBean.myChoicePeriod}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Month" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Week" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Year" />
             </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Do not use value attribute its inteded for different purpose

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "a little" late but probably the best solution is :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ToolsJIRA.myChoicePeriod}">
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="Month"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Week" itemValue="Week"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Year" itemValue="Year"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

P.S. Although is a late answer I posted it for others who will face the same problem

Answer (score 2):

`h:selectOneMenu` as a `value` accepts collection of [`SelectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) and you passed `String` and so the Exception.

Comment: yes I have noticed that ,but I followed this link :http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: It is jsf2.0 and seems you are trying it on jsf.1.2 or may be compare precisely

Comment: @@Jigar Joshi ,I'am using JSF2

Comment: @JigarJoshi `h:selectOneMenu as a value accepts collection of SelectItem`? This is obviously an incorrect statement.